# Packets & Garbages

Tags: visual-c++

I am trying to send message from Client to Server, but I faced an issue that the message is not a fixed length so I tried to put the total number of bytes/chars before the message. but the problem not solved. I started to get garbage on the server side and it is like the client keeps sending the same info but with more garbage.

Well before things working fine until I was trying to add something to previous code but lots of runtime errors and bugs. So i went this approach and it seems is the best thing.

and 2 more things,
1- Seems the buffer not emptying like keep adding even if it managed to read the first message where I could saw while debugging the code.
2- How can i empty the parts I read from the buffer which in my case is mybuffer

Windows 7
Visual C++ 2010 Express

Server code:

```
 char * GetMessage(int x, char arry [])
 {
char * msg = NULL;
msg = new char[x];
ZeroMemory(msg,x);

for(int i = 1; i <= x; i++)
{
    msg[i-1] = arry[i];
}

return msg;
  }

 void main(){

  char Filename[20];
            char Direction[4];
            char Type[1];
            bool FileExistOnClient;
            fstream fFile;
            FILE * iiFile;
            int strlength;
            char Hostname[20];
            int count = 0 ;
            char * ptr;


            ibytesrecv=0; 
            ZeroMemory(mybuffer,strlen(mybuffer));
            if((ibytesrecv = recv(s1,mybuffer,100,0)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
                throw "Receive failed\n";
            ptr = &mybuffer[0];
            count = atoi(ptr);
            sprintf(Hostname , GetMessage(count,mybuffer));
            cout <<mybuffer <<"\n";
            cout <<"Hostname is:" << Hostname << endl;
  }
```

Client Side:
     main(){
       ZeroMemory(mybuffer,strlen(mybuffer));

```
    mybuffer[0] = strlen(localhost)+48;
    strcat(mybuffer,localhost);
    ibytessent=0;    
    ibufferlen = strlen(mybuffer)  ;
    ibytessent = send(s,mybuffer,ibufferlen,0);
    if (ibytessent == SOCKET_ERROR)
        throw "Send failed\n";  


    //Send File name
    //ZeroMemory(mybuffer,strlen(mybuffer));
    mybuffer[strlen(mybuffer) ] = strlen(Filename)+48;
    strcat(mybuffer,Filename);
    ibytessent=0;    
    ibufferlen = strlen(mybuffer);
    ibytessent = send(s,mybuffer,ibufferlen,0);
    if (ibytessent == SOCKET_ERROR)
        throw "Send failed\n";  
 }
```

Comment: Lots of problems.  Using strcat() is just wrong, mybuffer is not a properly zero-terminated C string.  The receiving code just doesn't do anything with the transmitted length, a loop is required to ensure all bytes are received.

Comment: mybuffer length is 120, and I change the send buff length to 20, however, all what i am try to send wont exceed 30byte. and i have 3 send on client and 3 recv on server. So I think it should work. about strcat, what do you suggest to use instead of it?

Comment: You must use memcpy().  The number of bytes returned by rcve() is entirely unpredictable.

Comment: I am not sure if you noticed i was using strcat so i can insert the length of the message infront but now i cant do that because it is replacing everything. and 1 question do i need  to call //ZeroMemory(szbuffer,strlen(mybuffer));before every send/recv